Prove monotonicity of Ramsey number
I tried to prove $R(n_1,n_2,n_3) \geq R(n_1,n_2)$, but get stuck. I think it might be because I still do not get the essence of the definition of $R(n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k)$. It is the smallest $N$ such that if $K_N$ is $k$ colored, there is a $K_{n_1}$ in color $1$ or $K_{n_2}$ in color $2$ and so on. If we use less than $k$ colors to color  $K_R(n_1, n_2, \dots, n_k)$, what can we say for the results?
For example, $k=3$ and we use two colors, can I deliberately let color 3 = color 1, so we either have a $K_{n_1}$ in color $1$ or $K_{n_2}$ in color $2$ or $K_{n_3}$ in color $1$. I can also let color 3 = color 2 and say we either have a $K_{n_1}$ in color $1$ or $K_{n_2}$ in color $2$ or $K_{n_3}$ in color $2$.
Then how to show $R(n_1,n_2,n_3) \geq R(n_1,n_2)$? By coloring $K_{R(n_1,n_2,n_3)}$ in two colors, it seems I can not guarantee I have a $K_{n_1}$ in color 1 and $K_{n_2}$ in color 2. Because no matter let color 3 = color 1 (or color 2), if $n_3 <n_1$ and $n_3 <n_2$. We may only have a monochromatic $K_{n_3}$ in color 1 (or color 2), which is not enough.

That's essentially the argument. (It's not cleanly written up, so you might be confusing yourself, esp with the "let color 3 = ..." ). $\quad$ It's better to argue from the definition. IE For $R(n_1, n_2, n_3)$, you're guranrateed ether a $K_{n_1}, K_{n_2}, K_{n_3}$ in the corresponding colors. But if no color 3 edge is used, then we clearly cannot have a $K_{n_3}$, so we must have one of the other cases.

So the point is the three colors must be different. (Even though I may only use 2 of them). I can not do some trick like let color 3 = color 1?

I don't see why "the three colors must be different" affects my argument from the definition.  $\quad$ I would not try "color 3 = color 1", esp since you still seem to be thinking of them as 2 distinct colors. I would think of it as "color 3 does not get used".
